# Given a success on the kth trial, the probability of success on the mth trial

Tags: geometric-distribution

I know that this form of the Geometric distribution gives the probability that for a success probability $p$, the *k*th trial out of *k* trials is the first success.

$Pr(X=k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p$

My question is, conditioned on the first success happening on the *k*th trial, what would be the probability of a subsequent success occurring after the *m*th trial out of *m* trials.  To give some numbers, let's say that after 9 failures, we have a success on the 10th trial.  Now, given the success on the 10th trial, what would be the probability of say having 4 subsequent failures before a second success on the 5th trial?  In a sense, I'm asking about the probability of getting an interval of 4 failures between two successes.

Comment: Do you mean _after_ the $k$th trial, e.g. on the $k+4$th trial? Or do you mean _on_ the $k$th trial? If so, look into the gambler's fallacy.

Comment: What do you mean by "*a* success"? Do you mean "the *next* success"? Or just any success? If the latter, it's a trick question.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Or, if not a *trick*, the question is an invitation to prove the memoryless property of the geometric distribution.

Comment: @Sycorax True -- but the situation is even simpler than that, because it comes down to independence of outcomes.  After observing a success on trial $k,$ reset the count on the next trial from $k+1$ to $1$ and proceed. In terms of the new count the question becomes "what is the chance the next $m-k$ trials are all failures?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/377083/6633

Comment: @whuber I think the title and the body are mismatched -- the title says we've observed a success *on* the $k$th trial, which suggests independence, but the body says "given the first success happens *after* the $k$th trial," which is, I think, a question about memorylessness.

Comment: @Sycorax Good point -- there do appear to be multiple reasonable interpretations of the problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments.  I modified the question.  I'm essentially asking about the probability of observing a certain number of failures between two successes.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I mean on the *k*th trial

Comment: @whuber I think the way you phrased it is what I was looking for

Comment: @whuber Would you say that the answer to this involves the memoryless property of the geometric distribution?

Comment: I would say instead it involves the concept of independence: the chances of none of the outcomes after trial $k$ depend on the outcomes on or before trial $k.$